# Laptop Bluetooth pairing with iPhone

Tags: bluetooth, 19.10, iphone

Using Ubuntu 19.10 on a laptop, When I start Bluetooth the laptop can see the iPhone device, and the iPhone can see the laptop, but neither of them can 'connect'. I am guessing this is because they have not been 'paired' but there does not seem to be an option to do that.

What steps are needed to be able exchange files between an iPhone and a Laptop over Bluetooth? iPhone Airdrop works fine with other iPhones, and Bluetooth is enabled on both devices.